# Circular imports from another modules

Tags: python, import, fastapi

I've been having trouble in the last part of my first professional project, i created an API in fastapi using Python3.9,

in a file called "Services" i have my fun get_current_user() that actually needs imports CRUDUser to work, then, in my endpoint "Permission" y all for get_current_user() but then, this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'user' from partially initialized module 'src.components.users.crud' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/src/app/./src/components/users/crud.py)
```

Are there another ways to get an instance from CRUDUser to use on my endpoint? or to use where get_current_user() is and not to import CRUDUser?

A way to get CRUDUser instance without the "from path import user"

Answer (score 0):

Simply import the whole module rather than a name from it. `import src.components.users.crud` will work even with a partially-initialized module, since new names can always be added after it's imported into other modules and it will work fine. But you can't import a nonexistent name.

I'd write it as:

```py
import src.components.users.crud as crud
```

and then refer to it as `crud.user` whenever I needed it.